# Should a pom declare direct dependencies if also included transitively?

Tags: maven, maven-2

My module MyLibrary depends on artifact ThirdPartyLibrary.

My module MyApplication depends on MyLibrary but also directly invokes the code in ThirdPartyLibrary.

Should MyApplication explicitly include ThirdPartyLibrary as a dependency in the pom, or rely on the fact that MyLibrary includes it as a dependency?

Comment: If your code directly used ThirdPartyLibrary than explicitly define the dependency in your pom to make it clear that you use it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should declare every dependency that your application depends on directly, even if (at the moment) another of your direct dependencies exposes the same dependency transitively to your application. Here’s why: If you upgrade `MyApplication` to use a future version of `MyLibrary` which (unbeknownst to you) no longer depends on `ThirdPartyLibrary`, your code will suddenly fail to compile – until you add an explicit dependency on `ThirdPartyLibrary` to `MyApplication`. This means that this dependency should have been there all along.

FYI, the [`maven-dependency-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) has a very helpful [`dependency:analyze` goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) which assists you in figuring out which dependencies your application should declare; it will look through the code of `MyApplication`, see the dependency on `MyLibrary`, and issue a warning that `MyLibrary` is used, but undeclared:

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
[WARNING]    org.example:ThirdPartyLibrary:jar:1.0:compile
```

Answer (score 0):

I would mitigate [Andreas Sewe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6204208/andreas-sewe) answer and say that this is not an absolute rule.  If you use a popular framework like say Spring and your application requires the web components I always tell my colleagues to use maven's transitive dependency management and specify the highest level requirement which is in that case adding a dependency on spring-web.  I know that so far I have not contradicted Andreas reply.

However, if I have some code or later I add some code that depends on spring-core, spring-aop, spring-beans, spring-osm or spring-context (which are all transitive dependencies from spring-web) I do not recommend to add a declared dependency on any of them as this will increase the size of your POM files for dependencies that are part of the same framework.

If in a future version of spring-web a dependency is removed then yes as part of your upgrading activities, you should add that removed dependency (assuming you needed it).  My 2 cents.